# Prevent raising an exception

Tags: c#, parsing, exception, html-agility-pack, raiserror

I'm parsing the following html with the code below :

```
 var exroom = (from roomItem in
           doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dias']//h2")

       from s  in roomItem.NextSibling.NextSibling.SelectNodes(".//label")

       let rName = roomItem.InnerText.CleanInnerText()

       select new
       {
           roomID = rName,
           Pers = 2,
           Currency = "EUR",
           rateName = s.InnerText.CleanInnerText(),
           roomName = rName,
           Price = PriceHelper.Convert(PriceRegEx.Match(s.Attributes["precio"].Value.CleanInnerText()).Groups["price"].Value)
       }
).ToArray();
```

But when I parse the html content without the tags above, it raises an exception, how can I prevent raising an exception while parsing and return 0 for the exroom array ? such as I don't have any element in the class dias.

Comment: Is that `HtmlAgilityPack`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes it is

Comment: Why not return a 0-Length array instead of 0?

Comment: @bluewonder: Catching the exception and return something appropriate might probably not be the ideal solution but isn't it kind of self-suggesting?

Comment: I still cannot get how to handle an exception if the class dias contains no-elements in it @Jon

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Yes I get it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Split processing in three steps.

- select elements of class 'dias'
- check selected variable, and continue processing only if it is different than null
- rest of your processing

Because you have array of anonymous type objects in exroom variable creating empty array can be tricky.

I suggest wrapping that type in some class:

```
public class RoomItem {
    public string roomID { get; set; }
    public string Pers { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then selecting exroom variable would look like:

```
var diasElements = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dias']//h2");
var exroom = new RoomItem[] { };
if(null != diasElements) { 
    exroom = (from roomItem in diasElements
    from s in roomItem.NextSibling.NextSibling.SelectNodes(".//label")
    let rName = roomItem.InnerText.CleanInnerText()
    select new RoomItem
    {
         roomID = rName,
         Pers = 2,
         Currency = "EUR",
         rateName = s.InnerText.CleanInnerText(),
         roomName = rName,
         Price =
              PriceHelper.Convert(
                  PriceRegEx.Match(s.Attributes["precio"].Value.CleanInnerText()).Groups["price"].Value)
              }
    ).ToArray()
}
```

From your sample code it looks like empty list of elements with class 'dias' should result in some form of error message (maybe throw/catch exception, or adapt BookingEngineResponse to passing information about empty dias collection).

Edit:
Answer clarified after full code sample.

Comment: Thank you very much but I dont get the idea where you declare var exroom = new roomItem[] {};

Comment: @bluewonder It should be declared on the same level as 'var exroom = (from roomItem in' in your code sample.

Comment: @Wojtek This is the full code that I have, http://notepad.cc/share/PdWWsP2f4Y and as the exroom is returned with the elements in HTML, i dont know how to declare it at first

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you won't get exception if either of two `.SelectNodes()` in your LINQ yields no result. There are two other parts of your query that I think could raise exception :

1. Part with `NextSibling`, if current `roomItem` doesn't have next
   sibling or next next sibling. You can change this part to pure XPath
   instead of accessing `NextSibling` property. Using pure XPath is more save, it
   safely returns no result if no element match the entire query.
2. Part with `Attributes["precio"]`, if current `s` doesn't have attribute "precio". You can replace this part using `GetAttributeValue("attrName", "defaultValue")`, this method returns default value if the attribute doesn't exist.

Code that demonstrate above suggestions :

```
from roomItem in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='dias']//h2")
from s  in roomItem.SelectNodes("./following-sibling::*[2]//label")
let rName = roomItem.InnerText.CleanInnerText()
select new
{
   roomID = rName,
   Pers = 2,
   Currency = "EUR",
   rateName = s.InnerText.CleanInnerText(),
   roomName = rName,
   Price = PriceHelper.Convert(PriceRegEx.Match(s.GetAttributeValue("precio","").CleanInnerText()).Groups["price"].Value)
}
```

Comment: You're welcome @bluewonder. Consider to accept this answer if it fixed the problem. More info : [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)